# Open the start page in Visual Studio after closing a project?

Tags: visual-studio

When you start Visual Studio you get a start page with all the latest projects in a list.
But when you've opened and closed a project, how do you open that start page again?
(Without restarting VS)

Comment: I always wondered why the start page closes when you close a project, since it is not project specific by default.

Comment: Just noticed in VS2012 that you can choose to keep the start page open when loading a project. There's a check box below the projects list.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

### Visual Studio 2010-2015

There's a menu item `View -> Start Page`

Additionally you can choose to keep the start page open when loading a project. There's a check box below the projects list for that.

*(Tested in VS2010, VS2012, VS2013, VS2015)*

In current versions, you can also use the *Quick Launch* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) to search for the command
(Just type "*Start Page*" in *Quick Launch*)

### Visual Studio 2017

There's a menu item `File -> Start Page`

You can configure the behavior of the IDE on startup via `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Startup`.

In Visual Studio 2017, the start page will open automatically when the solution is closed. As far as I know, this cannot be changed directly in the IDE but there's an extension that adds that feature. See this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42701902/314334) and [this VSIX-Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BillMenees.MeneesVSTools2017) (but this will disable the start page completely - if you try to open it manually, it will be immediately closed automatically)

[image: Screenshot Visual studio 2017 Options]

Comment: In VS 2017, the start page will show up after closing a solution, even if At startup: Show Start Page is not selected.

Comment: Yeah, what mrsundquist said. That's great, but how do I turn the stupid thing off? It's annoying. Show empty environment doesn't stop it after I close a solution.

Comment: How to disable this Startup Page "feature"?

Comment: @Andrew Do you have any news about that?

Comment: @Maxim Yeah the news is this: IDE options are still as dishonest as our politicians and media.

Comment: The old VS2015 start page had a checkbox option to keep the start page open... I'm guessing that's gone, and there's no way to do that anymore? I love the start page, personally... gives me quick and easy access to all the solutions I work on. It's easier to use than going to File->Recent solutions, imho.

Answer (score 17):

You also have the Start Page icon in the toolbar :
[image: Start Page Icon]

Answer (score 12):

In VS2013 by default I do not see the "Start Page" command in the View menu but adding it was simple.    The icon also looks different in VS2013.

- Right click on the toolbar and choose **Customize...** at the bottom then go to **Commands**
- Switch to **Toolbar/Standard** and then click the **Add Command** button an locate the **View** group on the left
- Finally locate the **Start Page** item and click **OK**.

[image: Right click on the toolbar and choose **Customize...** at the bottom then go to **Commands**]

[image: Switch to **Toolbar/Standard** and then click the **Add Command** button an locate the **View** group on the left]

[image: Finally locate the **Start Page** item and click add.]

Comment: I think it is easier/quicker to click the Toolbar Options > Add or Remove Buttons icon next to the Standard toolbar then click Start Page.

Answer (score 5):

In VS 2017 the new location for viewing the start page
is under the 'file' menu. as appears in this link:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/4603/view-start-page-menu-item-is-missing.html

Answer (score 5):

In VS 2017 it's in File->Start Page.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

By now there is an **extension** exactly for that purpose:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e64380ab-e3aa-4ac7-aa11-95719c5c91e9

I tried it an it works like a charme in VS 2015 :)

Answer (score 4):

To get start page in visual studio 2017 Go to File -> Start Page

Answer (score 4):

In case of Visual Studio 2019, go to File->Start Window.

Comment: This applies also to VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be automatic in VS2008 - Anything you had open outside of any solution/project (including the start page) would close when you opened a project/solution, then when closed that product/solution it went back to what was open before.  That is how it should work, they broke it in VS2010.  So all the prior VS users searching for the answer - there is none - technology continues to regress.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [custom shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx) in VS under Tools > options > Environment > Keyboard.

makes it super easy to reopen the start page.
Here is my setup if you get confused
[custom start page shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmCUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2022 it's in Tools->Option->Environment->General->On Startup

Screenshot

[image: 1]