# How to keep start page open in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, production-environment

I can' find a setting to keep start page open in Visual Studio 2013, it closes down after opening a solution.
I find start page useful to pin recently used solutions, since my repository has hundreds of old solutions.

Comment: Did you try VIEW -> Start Page?

Comment: The option is on the Start page itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201260/open-the-start-page-in-visual-studio-after-closing-a-project

Comment: OH thanks Sergey! I had to **scroll** 10km down the start page to find that option :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open the start page in Visual Studio after closing a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201260/open-the-start-page-in-visual-studio-after-closing-a-project)