# Where is the Visual Studio 2017 start page menu item?

Tags: visual-studio

Where did the Visual Studio 2017 start page go in 2017? In 2015 it was on the View menu. Where did they move it to?

Comment: Please explain the down vote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open the start page in Visual Studio after closing a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201260/open-the-start-page-in-visual-studio-after-closing-a-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They moved it to the File menu.

Answer (score 2):

File > Start Page

it's the 3rd item under the File menu